# Whats wrong with this toggle function?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, image

I am having a simple `img` tag within `<p>` tag and If I click the img or the `<p>` tag the inner `div` should be `visible` and again If I click it it should `hide` the div.

I am getting it work for the first time but If I click the `img` or the `<P>` tag for the second the image dosent change.

I dont want the background image of the `<p>` should change I need it for the img tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
            $contentArea = $this.next('.content');

            if (!$contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.find('img').attr("src", "img/Minus.png");
                $(".content.active").slideToggle(500).removeClass('active');
                $contentArea.slideToggle(500).addClass("active");
            }
            else if ($contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.find('img').attr("src", "img/Plus.png");
                $(".content.active").slideToggle(500).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is how I'm showing it:

```
<div class="layer1">
    <p class="heading"><img src="img/Plus.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <p class="heading"><img src="img/Plus.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <p class="heading"><img src="img/Plus.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <p class="heading"><img src="img/Plus.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCgZy/)

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but attributes should be in quotes.  `<div class="content"></div>`

Comment: @Rocket-Sorry forgot to keep that actual in code I was having the quotes..

Comment: Do you want only one of the divs to be visible at a time?

Comment: @Connum-No not required.I thought it will look good if I keep all visible at at time if it brings me more problems then absolutely I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
else if ($contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.find('img').attr("src", "img/Plus.png");
    $(".content.active").slideToggle(500).addClass('active');
}
```

Should be:

```
else if ($contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.find('img').attr("src", "img/Plus.png");
    $(".content.active").slideToggle(500).removeClass('active');
}
```

You were hiding the active class and then adding active back onto it which was causing the problems.

If you don't care about more than one being expanded at a time then the code can be very simple:

```
jQuery(".heading").click(function () {       
    $('img.plus, img.minus', this).toggle();

    $(this).next('.content')
        .slideToggle(500);        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/PCgZy/3/

Comment: @Richard-I am able to work with toggling well but the image is not changing that's the main problem.toggling with the div works pretty well.

Comment: For toggle function this one line is working well  jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500); and for chnaging the image get the real headache.

Comment: @Richard-Thanks for the edit and demo anyways I got it working with the solution I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following in the if block:

```
$contentArea.slideToggle(500).addClass("active");
```

Shouldn't you have the inverse:

```
$contentArea.slideToggle(500).removeClass("active");
```

in the else block?

Comment: @jeanreis-It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have suceeded finally with this solution and here it goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
            $contentArea = $this.next('.content');

            if (!$contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.find('img').attr("src", "img/Minus.png");
                $contentArea.slideToggle(500).addClass("active");
            }
            else if ($contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.find('img').attr("src", "img/Plus.png");
                $contentArea.slideToggle(500).removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```